# Deploy multiple war files under the same root path on tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, war, pom.xml

I'm trying to deploy multiple spring war files with tomcat maven plugin each with a shared root path between them.

For example when I deploy now each app can be accessed by:

- localhost:8080/app1
- localhost:8080/app2

The desired paths would be:

- localhost:8080/apps/app1
- localhost:8080/apps/app2

Is this possible to do with multiple war files? I would like to keep this app decoupled from tomcat as much as possible as well so please take this into consideration as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `/apps` to each application's context path.